# Create password protected room using converse.js plugin

Tags: javascript, xmpp, chat, strophe, converse.js

I am trying to create password protected room.

I can create public room and configure password from configuration tab. But initially I have to create room as unsecured and public.

I want to create room with password protected, so I don't need to go to config tab to set password.

Is that possible to create room with password using just one call or one stanza. Right now I can do that with two manual operations of creating and configuring the room.

If anyone can provide stanza, that would be great help. I would like to know if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went round and round on this too. Had to do 2 calls to make it work.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I think this is the only solution.